# Magento: Static blocks stuck to each other

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, home-page

I'm new in Magento and trying to build a homepage which contains multiple static blocks. Every block contains images, text and buttons and using CSS I try to position those texts and buttons on top of the images. The problem is that if I use position:absolute to my first static block all the other blocks move over to that first image. How to make all static blocks be individual blocks even if position:relative and/or absolute is used?

Thanks!

Comment: Please visit below URL to build a homepage which contains multiple static blocks. http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-static-blocks-to-specific-cms-pages-with-magento-layouts/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to CSS and not to Magento.